# Regex to match everything from newline upto parenthesis along with a search term

Tags: php, regex

We're trying to parse information that's been output from an DOS based accounting software from the 90s, so we can convert and upload it to a newer system. It's mostly information pertaining to each accounting entry and it's output with random tabs, line breaks etc. like this:

```
#Ch. No. 209488 #Rt. Date 12-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2379;L:28)

#Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432;
L:28)

#Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997
#Bank: Citibank (R:2432;
L:28
)

#Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997
        #Bank: Citibank (R:2432;
    L:28
)
```

However, whats clear is that the information for each entry starts on a new line and ends with  a `)`

How can a regex that'll start looking for a term in that line all the way upto a `)` be written?

For example in the data above, we're looking for the string `Dr` using `preg_match_all('/^.*\b(?:Dr)\b.*$/m', $dos, $matches)` and it matches as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432;
            [1] => #Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997
            [2] => #Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997
        )

)
```

You can see from the second result in the array that it's omitted `#Bank: Citibank (R:2432; L:28)` since it's on a separate line, but that data is still part of the line above it.

How can the regex we're using be modified to match upto the next `)` regardless if it's on the same line or next line or even few more lines below? So the result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432;L:28)
            [1] => #Ch. No. 759263 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432;L:28)
            [2] => #Ch. No. 395159 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432;L:28)
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` to match any char except the parenthesis which will also match a newline.

After the match you can replace all whitespace chars with a single space.

```
^.*\bDr\b[^()]*\([^()]+\)
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\bDr\b` Match 0+ times any char except a newline and then match Dr between word boundaries (Or match `#Dr\b` if it always start with `#`)
- `[^()]*` Match 0+ times any char except parenthesis
- `\(` Match `(`
- `[^()]+` Match 1+ times any char except parenthesis (if there has to be at least a single char not being `(` `)` in between
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4XcD7z/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/a1JlR)

For example

```
$re = '/^.*\bDr\b[^()]*\([^()]+\)/m';
$str = '#Ch. No. 209488 #Rt. Date 12-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2379;L:28)

#Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432;
L:28)

#Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997
#Bank: Citibank (R:2432;
L:28
)

#Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997
        #Bank: Citibank (R:2432;
    L:28
)';

$result = preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$result = array_map(function($x) {
    return preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', $x);
}, $matches[0]);
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => #Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432; L:28)
    [1] => #Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432; L:28 )
    [2] => #Ch. No. 884273 #Dr. Date 10-09-1997 #Ch. Dep. 14-09-1997 #Bank: Citibank (R:2432; L:28 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to @CBroe comment I came up with this:

`/(#[^\)\n]*(?:#Dr).*\)\n*)/gsU`

- `#[^\)\n]*` -> starts with `#` and prevent to search through all characters that pass `)` or `\n` (new line).
- `(?:#Dr)` -> the search string in none capturing group.
- `.*\)\n*` -> continue until meet a `)` or a `\n` (new line).
- `gsU` -> used flags: g: global search, s: matches new lines, U: ungreedy quantifiers.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Weazd7/2)